# Unable to Authenticate REST Api using F# and RestSharp for Mailgun

Tags: f#, restsharp, mailgun

I'm tring to use restsharp in F# to call the Mailgun API.

I modelled it on the sample C# code from Mailgun but I can't get it going.

The problem code is:

```
    let client: RestClient = 
        new RestClient(
            BaseUrl = Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3")
        )
        
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("","")
```

This expression was expected to have type IAuthenticator' but here has type 'HttpBasicAuthenticator'

It seems that somehow the inherited type for one is different than the expected type which doesn't make sense to me. The HttpBasicAuthenticator object says it inherits from authentocatorBase

Comment: Are you trying to assign to client.Authenticator? You need to use the assignment operator, <-, not = (which is the equality operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but most likely you have to cast the new object to the interface. F# requires it.

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("","") :> IAuthenticator
```

Have a look at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/

Comment: You can also let the compiler infer the interface type via `:> _`.